# Como enviar as mensagens respectivas aos e-mails vindo do banco de dados com php mailer?

Tags: php, aplicação-web, while, phpmailer

**ATENÇÃO: SOLUÇÂO NO FINAL DA POSTAGEM**

Estou finalizando um projeto no entanto estou enroscado na seguinte situação!
Estou fazendo um sistema de Newsletter onde no banco de dados tem três campos, o de permissão para enviar, o campo e-mail, e um com código de cancelamento único para cada cadastro! Na hora que envio os múltiplos destinatários com o PHP mailer até funciona, ele envia para os todos do While normalmente, no entanto o código de cancelamento dos respectivos e-mail não está indo certo,somente o primeiro código do laço está sendo enviado para todos!

segue código

```
 $check_newsletter =$mysqli->query("SELECT email,desassinar_code FROM newsletter WHERE permissao ='sim'");

 include_once("inc/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

                $mail = new PHPMailer;
                $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->Host = "$host_config";
                $mail->Port = "$port_config";
                $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
                $mail->Username = "$email_config";
                $mail->Password = "$senha_config";
                $mail->SetFrom ($email_config,$title_web);
                $mail->addReplyTo('no-reply@email.com.br');
                if($title_web!=''){
                $mail->FromName = "$title";
                }                    
                $mail->Subject=$titulo;     
                $mail->WordWrap=50;
                $mail->IsHTML(true);


            while($n_p=$check_newsletter->fetch_array()){ 

              $body = "Para deixar de receber esse e-mails, cancele sua inscrição <a href='".url."/cancel-newsletter/".$n_p['desassinar_code']."'><strong style='color:#3C8FDC;'>clicando aqui</strong>";
              $mail->msgHTML($body);  
              $mail->AddBCC($n_p['email']);  

        }



        if($mail->Send()){           
            ...
            }else{
               ...    
            }
```

É isso galera, está faltando vários pedaços do código que creio que não entram em questão, agradeço a todos.

OBS:ja tentei mudar algumas posições, como por o "$mail->msgHTML($body)", para fora do laço, mais para cima, ou para baixo e nada...

**SOLUÇÃO**

Fazendo uma pesquisa em outros tópicos e testando consegui resolver alterando o loop (while) para:

```
    while($n_p=$check_newsletter->fetch_array()){   
              $mail->clearAllRecipients();  // Não esqueça isso 
              $mail->addAddress($n_p['pca_email']); // addAddress era addBBC  
              $mail->Body = "Para deixar de receber esse e-mails, cancele sua inscrição <a href='".url."/cancel-newsletter/".$n_p['pca_desassinar_code']."'><strong style='color:#3C8FDC;'>clicando aqui</strong>";                                 
              $sucess_news = $mail->Send(); 

}


    O método "clearAllRecipients();" É muito importante, pois ele limpará o destinatário da última volta para que a seção 'para' do email não mostre todos os destinatários do boletim.
```

Comment: todos os e-mails são formatos de e-mail validos?

Comment: Sim, tenho todo um sistema administrativo operando e gerenciando esses detalhes, alias, o código está enviando os e-mail e chegando na caixa de entrada normalmente, o  que eu precisava era que o código de cancelamento que coloco no while "bd $n_p['desassinar_code']" também chegasse em cada um dos respectivos emails que estão no loop, mas somente o primeiro código está chegando em todas, a leitura esta repetindo o primeiro código para todos destinatário!

Comment: repare que no "$body" está indo um código de cancelamento para cada um! mas somente o primeiro código do bd vai para todos destinatários muito estranho, até parece que estou dando echo fora do laço de repetição

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, na verdade você não tá dando o echo fora do laço, e sim mandando somente o ultimo código do laço.
O código de `$mail->Send()` e seu respectivo IF deve estar dentro do laço while.
Na realidade só está indo para TODOS pois você adiciona o BCC dentro do laço, o correto seria a cada volta do laço você gerar um novo e-mail reiniciando o OBJETO, imagina que este laço tem 500 emails, o primeiro usuário vai receber 500 cópias do mesmo email.
o correto seria:

```
    $check_newsletter =$mysqli->query("SELECT email,desassinar_code FROM newsletter WHERE permissao ='sim'");
include_once("inc/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
while($n_p=$check_newsletter->fetch_array()){ 
$body = "Para deixar de receber esse e-mails, cancele sua inscrição <a href='".url."/cancel-newsletter/".$n_p['desassinar_code']."'><strong style='color:#3C8FDC;'>clicando aqui</strong>";
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host = "$host_config";
    $mail->Port = "$port_config";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Username = "$email_config";
    $mail->Password = "$senha_config";
    $mail->SetFrom ($email_config,$title_web);
    $mail->addReplyTo('no-reply@email.com.br');
    if($title_web!=''){
        $mail->FromName = "$title";
    }                    
    $mail->Subject=$titulo;     
    $mail->WordWrap=50;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->msgHTML($body);  
    $mail->AddBCC($n_p['email']);  
    if($mail->Send()){           
        ...
    }else{
        ...    
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá testei sua solução e funcionou legal, antes deu aplica lá fiz uma busca profunda em outros tópicos e também cheguei em outra solução que deu certo! Creio que é melhor desta maneira de acordo com essa documentação: "https://www.greenarrowemail.com/docs/greenarrow-engine/Injecting-Mail/SimpleMH-Injection/PHPMailer-SimpleMH-Multiple-Recipient-Example" não é necessário reiniciar o objeto, o loop é feito no mesmo lugar, acho que da maneira do link evita um sobrecarrego de memoria tendo em vista vários cadastros. Basicamente adicionei clearAllRecipients(); e o $mail->send(); dentro do laço

Comment: Logo mais, vou editar a postagem adicionando a solução para o tópico!

Comment: Exato! Na verdade, não procurei a documentação do PHPMailer, e sim só me atentei ao código que estava na questão, realmente lendo a documentação postada, fica mais performático, memória poucos bytes por volta, já que o objeto está sendo reescrito, e não criando-se uma nova instância dele.

Comment: Editado! Obrigado.